# How to rewrite Dlib's Python code in C++?

Tags: python, c++, dlib

I've written a python code using dlib, but because of project especifications, I need to rewrite the same code in C++. It's almost all done, but the most important I couldn't find the exactly equivalent in C++.

The python version is:

```
[boxes, confidences, detector_idxs] = dlib.fhog_object_detector.run_multiple(detectors, image, upsample_num_times=1, adjust_threshold=0.0)
```

The C++ I've tried is:

```
vector<rectangle> detection = evaluate_detectors(detectors, img, adjust_threshold);
```

I still didn't run the code, but I'm not sure if this function I've used in C++ will return the three infos (boxes, confidences, detector_idxs) like in python, from what I can see, I think it will return only the boxes.

Do you know if I'm doing it the right way? How can I get these three info I need?

**EDIT 01:**
Erros using the function:

```
tuple<std::vector<dlib::rectangle>, list<T> confidences>, list<T> detector_idxs> = run_multiple_rect_detectors(detectores, img, upsampling_amount, adjust_threshold);

error C2065: 'T': undeclared identifier

error C2923: 'std::list': 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

error C2903: 'allocator': symbol is neither a class template nor a function template

error C3203: 'allocator': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Alloc', expected a real type

error C2146: syntax error: missing '>' before identifier 'confidences'

error C2059: syntax error: ','
```

**EDIT 01-1:**

```
error C2872: 'rectangle': ambiguous symbol
note: could be 'dlib::rectangle'
note: or       'rectangle'
error C2146: syntax error: missing '>' before identifier 'rectangles'
error C2653: 'pybind11': is not a class or namespace name
error C3861: 'run_multiple_rect_detectors': identifier not found
```

After fixing syntax errors shown by VS:

```
error C3861: 'run_multiple_rect_detectors': identifier not found
```

**EDIT 02:**

```
Error   C2027   use of undefined type 'dlib::image_traits<image_type>'
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'pixel_type'
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: You can check the source code for the Python binding and see what it delegates to.

Comment: You should take a look at the [C++ HOG object detector example](http://dlib.net/fhog_object_detector_ex.cpp.html). Its quite simple for C++ standards.

Comment: Why rewrite code that works? Call the python code from C++.

Comment: I'm also trying to use the FHOG in C++, but I'm having some trouble with the variables type, it's not so easy as in python

Comment: @NicolasZ. DLib is a heavily templated library. I recommend having a look at C++ templates first. C++ is vastly different to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`run_multiple(...)` looks like its calling [run_multiple_rect_detectors(...)](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/tools/python/src/simple_object_detector_py.h), 
Assuming it is, you should be able to call:

```
std::tuple<std::vector<rectangle> rectangles, std::vector<double> confidences, std::vector<unsigned long> detector_idxs> detection = dlib::run_multiple_rect_detectors(detectors, img, 1, 0.0);
```

`1` is the up-sample amount and `0.0` is the threshold.

since pybind automatically translates between C++11 and Python tuples.

You can then separate the tuple into the different vectors with std::vector rectangles = detection.first(), and so on for detection.second() and detection.third().

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't work, I've got several errors calling this function on VS2017

Comment: This code is glorified pseudocode; I don't know the types of `confidences`, `detector_idxs`, nor the arguments for the function. Make sure compiling against the pybind library is successful. Also, if you edit the question with the stack trace, I would be glad to help.

Comment: Sorry for taking too long to answer, I'll edit the question now

Comment: That's fine, I've edited my answer with hopefully working code.

Comment: I've tested your code jackw11111, but I've got some erros trying to run it, I edited my question with it (EDIT 01-1). I've fixed some syntax errors that VS has shown, but the function  run_multiple_rect_detectors() I couldn't call from any header file, I've tried a lot of them. I was looking on the web and I've seen the c++ function evaluate_detectors() that I tried is the might be the right one, but unfortunately I'm getting erros when running it (EDIT 02).

Comment: Have you tried specifiying the namespace as well, `dlib::run_multiple_rect_detectors(...)`? Also, if you look the source code file I linked, in the body of `run_multiple_rect_detectors()`, you can see that it calls `run_detectors_with_upscale1` which will call `evaluate_detectors`.

Comment: I've got it, I did my own version of get_frontal_face_detector() for other object, with this I don't need to call an external svm file. I definetly can say that it was easier than what I was trying to do before. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Persistence pays dividends, glad it's sorted and you're welcome.